# Kotlin class implementing Java interface error

Tags: java, class, interface, kotlin, implementation

I've got a Java interface

```
public interface SampleInterface extends Serializable {
    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);
}
```

and a Kotlin class that is supposed to implement it

```
open class ClazzImpl() : SampleInterface

private val id: Unit? = null

fun getId(): Long? {
    return null
}

fun setId(id: Long?) {

}
```

However I get a compilation error:

> Class ClazzImpl is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
>   public abstract fun setId(id: Long!): Unit defined in
>   com....SampleInterface

any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers from Egor and tynn are important, but the error you have mentioned in the question is not related to their answers.

You have to add curly braces first.

```
open class ClazzImpl() : SampleInterface {

  private val id: Unit? = null

  fun getId(): Long? {
    return null
  }

  fun setId(id: Long?) {

  } 

}
```

If you add the curly braces, that error would have gone but you will get a new error like this:

> 'getId' hides member of supertype 'SampleInterface' and needs
>   'override' modifier

Now, as suggested in the other answers, you have to add override modifier to the functions:

```
open class ClazzImpl() : SampleInterface {

      private val id: Unit? = null

      override fun getId(): Long? {
        return null
      }

      override fun setId(id: Long?) {

      } 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the `override` keyword before `fun`:

```
override fun getId(): Long? {
    return null
}

override fun setId(id: Long?) {
}
```

Comment: Looks like the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) are pretty explicit indeed: "[...]we stick to making things explicit in Kotlin. And unlike Java, Kotlin requires explicit annotations for overridable members (we call them open) and for overrides[...]"

Answer (score 2):

When you implement an interface within *Kotlin*, you have to make sure to override the interface methods **inside** of the class body:

```
open class ClazzImpl() : SampleInterface {

    private var id: Long? = null

    override fun getId(): Long? {
        return id
    }

    override fun setId(id: Long?) {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```